# Why is United States Gross Capital Formation per capita so far ahead of the big 3 European economies?

Tags: usa, capital-structure

So, I was pondering the weakness of the UK economy (I am British) and its lagging productivity performance.  I was thinking that capital deployed per worker would be an explanatory variable.

Looking at figures from www.tradingeconomics.com: Gross Fixed Capital Formation data : [Germany](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/germany/gross-fixed-capital-formation)
|[United Kingdom](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/united-kingdom/gross-fixed-capital-formation)|[France](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/france/gross-fixed-capital-formation)|[United States](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/united-states/gross-fixed-capital-formation).

Dividing through by population (proxy for working population) I get the following per capita figures

```
UK       $1,506.79 
Germany  $1,860.17 
France   $1,858.21 
USA      $8,715.27
```

If the Sterling/dollar exchange before Brexit were used then the three European economies are very close to each at $1800.  But the key standout is the USA figure its miles ahead.

So I am now wondering why is United States Gross Capital Formation per capita so far ahead of the big 3 European economies?

Comment: Are you comparing quarterly or annual figures, or possibly annual for US only?  Looking at the OECD figures for 2014 (http://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/economics/national-accounts-of-oecd-countries_2221433x - click on Read to access the table for a country, for pdf you need to subscribe) the disparity appears much less.

Comment: @Adam Bailey: ah, I will check my figures.